# How do I specify regular expression for this jar in ant build?

Tags: regex, ant

Here is the ant statement -

```
 <java jar="${lib.dir}/selenium-server-standalone-2.8.0.jar" fork="true" spawn="true" />
```

And I want to do -

```
 <java jar="${lib.dir}/selenium-server-*.jar" fork="true" spawn="true" />
```

Hence I am not affected with version of jar I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ant `java` task doesn't support regular expressions there.  But you can use a [fileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) to 'find' the jar:

```
<fileset dir="${lib.dir}" id="selenium.jar" includes="selenium-server-*.jar" />
```

Then you can refer to the file using the [`ant.refid:`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html#ant.refid) prefix:

```
<java jar="${ant.refid:selenium.jar}" fork="true" spawn="true" />
```

If your library directory contains multiple versions of the jar this won't work: you need to decide which one to chose.
You could look into using a resource collection like [`first`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#first) to pick just one, but I'm not sure that would necessarily give you the *right* one.